# Errors in link ReCaptcha and Extension Directory

Tags: error

In version 5.19.3 and in the demo.civicrm.org are errors in links.

Administer > System Settings > Misc, the first link reCaptcha is with additional quotes around target. The link is working but opened in the same tab.

Administer > System Settings > Payment Processors, in the Payment Processors Help, the link one for Extension Directory is wrong. The same error for the Extension Directory : Display Preferences, the help WYSIWYG Editor.

Comment: Thanks for noting these.  Would you be interested in creating a PR for these?  It would be a nice 'first PR' to get started with contributing code changes to Civi.